# Functions, Continuity and IVT

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $g$ is a function defined and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $n$ is a positive integer such that
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{g(x)}{x^n} = 0 = \lim_{x\to -\infty} \dfrac{g(x)}{x^n}$$

(i) If $n$ is odd, show that there is some $x$ such that $g(x) + x^n = 0$.

(ii) If $n$ is even, show that there is some $c$ such that $g(c) + c^n \leq g(x) + x^n$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

${{{}}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) Let $f(x):=g(x)+x^n$, then we have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=1$. So, if $n$ is odd, then as  $x\to-\infty$, $\ x^n<0$ so there must be (plenty of) such $x<0$ where $f(x)<0$. Similarly, looking at $x\to\infty$ there must be some $x$ where $f(x)>0$. (Moreover, $\lim_{\pm\infty}f=\pm\infty$.) Since $f$ is continuous, it then must also vanish somewhere.

(ii) If $n$ is even, again, $f(x)$ must be approximately $x^n$ both around $-\infty$ and $\infty$, this time it implies $f(x)>0$ values and $\lim_{\pm\infty}f=+\infty$. The claim that $f$ must have a global minimum value already follows from this property: 
Maybe the easiest way is to consider the exntension $\bar{\Bbb R}:=\Bbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ which is *compact*, then $f$ extends to a $\bar{\Bbb R}\to\bar{\Bbb R}$ continuous function which never takes the value $-\infty$, but its image has to be compact.